# The more... the more

Tags: grammar

I have another question. Please take a look at the following sentence (error correction)

> The **more** Robert *tried to* please his mother with mere flattery, **the greater** he **succeeded in** annoying her.

In the said sentence, the answer key says that the wrong part is the "the greater", which, accordingly, must be replaced with " the more greatly".

Why is " the greater" wrong here? I haven' t used " the more greatly" before, as this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"succeed" is a verb. Verbs are modified by adverbs, but "great" and "greater" are adjectives. To turn an adjective into an adverb, you can add the "-ly" suffix, hence "greatly". Since you can't also use the "-er" suffix to express degree ("greaterly" is not a word), you have to use the word "more" to modify it.

However, in my opinion, "the more greatly" sounds awkward. I would write

> The more robert tried to please his mother with mere flattery, the more he succeeded in annoying her.